# Can't draw a filled rectangle in iPhone 5S and iPad Air

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

This code draws a filled rectangle:

```
void ccDrawFilledRect( CGPoint v1, CGPoint v2 )
{
    CGPoint poli[]={v1,CGPointMake(v1.x,v2.y),v2,CGPointMake(v2.x,v1.y)};

    // Default GL states: GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_VERTEX_ARRAY, GL_COLOR_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY
    // Needed states: GL_VERTEX_ARRAY,
    // Unneeded states: GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY, GL_COLOR_ARRAY
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, poli);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);

    // restore default state
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

It has always worked, until I begun using an iPhone 5S and iPad Air. I don't understand why doesn't it work with those devices - it was fine with all others. Always using the latest iOS version.

What might it be?

I doubt it matters, but I've been using `cocos2d-iphone 1.0.1`.

Comment: 2nd question of yours using v1.0 - if this is a new project i strongly recommend using at least cocos2d v2 (unless you work off a book or tutorial), v1 has absolutely no support for and is largely untested on the newer devices. There will be more issues.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D: Yeah, you know I've been into `1.0.1` for ages, but heck, the game is so close to completion now :[... I've been wanting to move on to `3.0`, but the refactoring is intimidating.

Comment: Okay, maybe you can take a day or two and try to lift a copy of your project up to at least v2.0. It's not as much refactoring as for v3 (99% of it is just renaming classes/methods/properties) and still a much better codebase.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D: I heard that prior to v3 there's no real support for arm64. Since I'm probably not going to update to v3, should I remove arm64 from the valid architectures? What are the implications of doing that? Would the iPhone 5S be unable to run the game? (well, I just tested and it does work, but I dunno).

Comment: Yes, remove arm64 architecture. The iphone 5s runs armv7(s) code just as well. v1 and v2 of cocos clearly have 32-64 bit conversion issues, so there may be truncation of values on 64bit systems leading to rounding errors or worse. For instance if a method is defined to take a float parameter but the caller sends it a double (CGFloat) depending on how the call is made the received value will always be 0. There is at least one such case reported, and other potential issues were located as well, for instance the entire cgpointextension module uses float or even a mixture of float and cgfloat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed.

```
void ccDrawFilledRect( CGPoint v1, CGPoint v2 ) {

    float vertices[] = {
        v1.x,  v1.y,      // Bottom left
        v2.x,  v1.y,  // Bottom right
        v2.x,  v2.y, // Top right
        v1.x, v2.y // Top left
    };

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);

    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

No, I have absolutely no idea why did the old code fail in the iPhone 5S and iPad Air, but this new code seems to work on all devices now.

Comment: Thanks for this! It helped me figure out why my code wasn't work. Turns out in 32bit CGPoint is two floats and on 64bit devices, it is two doubles (so twice the size). Which means the vertices are totally wrong on the 64 bit. When you use the float vertices, it works correctly. I was having this issue when moving to iOS with 64 bit only.

Comment: @christophercotton good to know! Me from 3 years ago can rest in peace now :]